# How to add alert in Azure monitor for VM insight metrics?

Tags: azure, monitor

I enabled the VM insights for few VMs. How can I create alerts for those metrics in Azure monitor?

Comment: Is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/alert-metric) what you want to find?

Comment: That is pretty much it but when creating new alert I am unable to find those metrics provided by insights to alerts.

Comment: Do you filter by resource type-virtual machines when you select a target?

Comment: Yes I select virtual machines as resource type. Then configure alert criteria but I cannot find for example the memory metrics.

Comment: It seems that no memory metrics even you look at the metrics from each of VM setting. But you can find Percentage CPU metrics both from VM setting and creating an alert. You only create alert for existing metrics.

Comment: But I thought that the VM insights would enable me to monitor guest OS as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I create alerts for those metrics in Azure monitor?

You can not create alerts for the metrics provided by VM insights. [VM insight preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/rich-insights-for-virtual-machines-from-azure-monitor/) provides an in-depth view of VM health, performance trends, and dependencies. You can create [these metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftcomputevirtualmachines) alert for VM.

Moreover, Standard or Platform metrics are limited, you can try to make [custom metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/metrics-custom-overview) via a variety of methods on your Azure VM to collect some custom performance indicators or business-specific metrics to provide deeper insights. Once published to Azure Monitor, you can alert on custom metrics for your Azure resources side by side the standard metrics emitted by Azure.

Ref: [Send guest OS metrics to the Azure Monitor metric store using a Resource Manager template for a Windows Virtual Machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/metrics-store-custom-guestos-resource-manager-vm)

Comment: Does this mean that I cannot create alerts for the metrics provided by VM insights?

Comment: Yes, currently, you only can create [these metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftcomputevirtualmachines) alert for VM.

Comment: @NancyXiong Does this mean I cannot add alerts on metrics provided by Guest OS (like Memory %Bytes in use) in an Azure VM?

Comment: @Garima  no, you could enable extended metrics for guest-os level monitoring like memory, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management/azure-vm-extended-metrics

Comment: @NancyXiong yes I have already done that but wants to set up alerts on it. As far as I know, it used to be possible in classic alerts

Comment: @Garima I agree, currently, there are no signals for alerting classic metric.